# Why WPF ignores my CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

Tags: mysql, wpf, entity-framework, binding, cultureinfo

I started messing up with MySQL.Data.EntityFramework (8.0.15) and I'm getting wrong date format.

In my culture ('pl-PL') date format is "YYYY-MM-DD", but DataGrid shows dates in "MM/DD/YYYY" format by default. My Windows regional settings are correct.

```
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); // shows pl-PL
```

My binding initially was like this:

```
<!-- wrong date format -->
Binding="{Binding date}"
```

Setting ConverterCulture in Binding worked:

```
<!-- correct date format -->
{Binding date, ConverterCulture='pl-PL', StringFormat=d}
```

but **I don't want to set ConverterCulture everywhere**.

My question is:

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Check CurrentUICulture property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
```

And maybe, you need to take a look to

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
    XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

Comment: `FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(...)` helped. Thank you!

Comment: I'd like to add, that though `FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(...)` is a standard solution, it works only for `FrameworkElement`s but not for `FrameworkContentElement`s like `Run`. If you will need to use Binding with them, you can create a class inherited from `Binding` and set the property `ConverterCulture` to `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` in constructor. Then you can use your custom binding with FramewordContentElements.